# How to echo variables from specific PHP arrays using multiple dropdown lists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm fairly new to PHP so please bear with me. I'm trying to find a solution to a multi dropdown/array problem which seems quite complex to me, but hopefully there's a simple solution. I'm not using any databases, just the arrays stored in the file.

I have three html dropdown lists:

```
<form action="">
<select name="size">
<option value="large" selected>Large</option>
<option value="small">Small</option>
</select>

<select name="colour">
<option value="warm" selected>Warm</option>
<option value="cold">Cold</option>
</select>

<select name="object">
<option value="fruit" selected>Fruit</option>
<option value="clothes">Clothes</option>
<option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and multiple PHP arrays for use with said forms.

```
$large = ("massive", "large", "extra large");
$small = ("tiny", "little", "small");
$warm = ("red", "yellow", "orange");
$cold = ("blue", "green", "purple");
$fruit = ("apple", "banana", "pear");
$clothes = ("hat", "sock", "jumper");
$bird = ("raven", "eagle", "owl");
```

I am attempting to do the following.

When the user selects an option from each of the three dropdown lists, the text that's echoed underneath changes depending on the arrays selected.

Example:

- User selects Large, Warm and Bird.

  > Echoed result is: "A massive, red owl", or "a large yellow raven".
- User selects Small, Cold and Fruit.

  > Echoed result is: "A tiny, blue apple" or any other variation.

Is there any way to do this using php, JavaScript and/Ajax or any other method?

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
<?php
$size = array('large' => array("massive", "large", "extra large"),
              'small' => array("tiny", "little", "small")
              );
$colour = array('warm' => array("red", "yellow", "orange"),
                'cold' => array("blue", "green", "purple")
                );
$object = array('fruit' => array("apple", "banana", "pear"),
                'clothes' => ("hat", "sock", "jumper"),
                'bird' => ("raven", "eagle", "owl")
                );

?>

<script>
$(function() {
    var selections = {
        size: <?php echo json_encode($size) ?>,
        colour: <?php echo json_encode($colour) ?>,
        object: <?php echo json_encode($object) ?>
    };

    $('select').change(function() {
        var which = this.name;
        var items = selections[which][this.value];
        var pick = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]; // Pick random item
        $("#show_"+which).text(pick);
    });
});
</script>

<form action="">
    <select name="size">
    <option value="large" selected>Large</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    </select>

    <select name="colour">
    <option value="warm" selected>Warm</option>
    <option value="cold">Cold</option>
    </select>

    <select name="object">
    <option value="fruit" selected>Fruit</option>
    <option value="clothes">Clothes</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="output">
A <span id="show_size"></span>, <span id="show_colour"></span> <span id="show_object"></span>
</div>
```

It uses `json_encode` to convert the PHP arrays into Javascript arrays. Then when you select an item from one of the menus, it uses that to find a sub-array in the object, picks a random element of it, and displays it in the corresponding span below.

Comment: Ah, this is great. I'd never even heard of json_encode before. Is it possible to alter the code so that the text only displays and can be refreshed (with a new random result) when a submit button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, you can attach the code to the `click` method of a button instead of the `change` method of the `select`.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get it to work the way I need it to. When I change the code to work with click and a submit button, it no longer displays anything. I tried editing the select.change function and added:

    $('submit').change(function() {
         var pick = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]; // Pick random item
        $("#show_"+which).text(pick);
    })

after it, but still had no luck. What could I do the get it to display the selections only when submit is pressed, then display new random variables from the selected arrays when submit is pressed again?